# Grails 3.x multiple datasources

Tags: grails, datasource

Back in Grails 2.x world I could create multiple dataSources in an environment:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        ...
    }
    dataSource_new {
        ...
    }
}
```

and reference them in the controller:

```
def db = new SQL(dataSource_new)
```

and everything worked awesome.  In Grails 3.x, everything is not awesome:

```
development:
    dataSource:
        ...
    dataSource_new:
        ...
```

and calling

```
def db = new SQL(dataSource_new)
```

throws:

```
Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#
```

Anyone have success with this (or can point out what's changed that I've missed)?

Tried mapping in domain with no luck:

```
class abc {
    String ...

    static mapping = {
        datasource: ['DEFAULT', 'dataSource_new']
}
```

throws:

```
Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#<init>. Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between: [interface java.sql.Connection] [interface javax.sql.DataSource]
```

Answer (score 1):

In official docs you can find an example for injecting datasource into service:

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources

```
class DataService {
    static datasource = 'lookup'

    void someMethod(...) {
        //…
    }
}
```

or into command:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html

```
import grails.dev.commands.*
import javax.sql.*
import groovy.sql.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*

class RunQueryCommand implements ApplicationCommand {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    boolean handle(ExecutionContext ctx) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        println sql.executeQuery("select * from foo")
        return true
    }
}
```

Moreover look at this thread and quoted examples: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/701

Comment: Throws up all over me; mapping the datasources in the domain works if i only have one ('DEFAULT'); adding a second spits out an unmapped class error.  If i swap my 2nd datasource for the default everything (on one page) works great -- if only i didn't have other pages!

Comment: Tried to inject it as a service but not familiar enough with how to implement; appears to be the solution based on others' experiences.

Comment: I'm not sure what your first comment mean. Could you be more specific? What have you tested and what was a stacktrace for each solution? (you can edit your question) Moreover maybe it's simply a problem with declaration of the second datasource?

Comment: mapped the datasource in my domain class (see original post since comments hate code

Answer (score 0):

I work with multiply datasources in Grails 3.x like following:

assuming you have configuration:

```
development {
  dataSources {
    dataSource {
      url = 'your_url'
      password = 'psw'
      ...
    }
    second {
      url = 'you_url_2'
      password = 'psw2'
      ...
    }
}
```

So in a service you will have mapped data source like this: 
`dataSource_second`

And to create Sql instance you will need to do the following:

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource_second)
```

It works in Grails 3.0.11.
Hope it will help.

Comment: That's datasources.groovy, I believe, which is what 2.x used; 3.x is using .yml files which look more like python than an array (use colons instead of braces).  This is what used to work so well!

Comment: You can use .groovy in 3.x

Comment: Have you tried this idea with yml? I guess it should work

Comment: Started off with that format in yml and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working when that had worked in previous versions as .groovy; will try using .groovy and see if that works -- didn't know it'd still work

Comment: yml should work with the service injection (saw a different user implement that approach) but am not familiar with that usage; took a stab @ it with no success.  declared the 2nd datasource in the service and called the service in the controller but don't know where to go from there.