# Grails 3.0.9 Error on using Multiple DataSources in application.yml

Tags: grails

I searched for this and none of the answers worked for me. I am trying to use multiple dataSources in my application and have declare the same in my application.yml file. Below is my application.yml file.

application.yml

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: testingwebsockets
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none

    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            userLookup:
                userDomainClassName: 'lnmsconfig.SecUser'
         # LDAP config
            providerNames: 'ldapAuthProvider' # specify this when you want to skip attempting to load from db and only use LDAP
            ldap:
                context:
                    managerDn: 'CN=netcool,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=syniverse,DC=com'
                    managerPassword: 'xxx'
                    server: 'xxx'
                search:
                    base: 'DC=ad,DC=syniverse,DC=com'
                    filter: 'sAMAccountName={0}' # for Active Directory you need this
                    searchSubtree: true
                auth:
                    hideUserNotFoundExceptions: false
                useRememberMe: false
                authorities:
                    ignorePartialResultException: true # typically needed for Active Directory
                    retrieveGroupRoles: true
                    groupSearchBase: 'OU=Syniverse,DC=ad,DC=syniverse,DC=com'
                    groupSearchFilter: 'member={0}'
---
hibernate:
    jdbc:
        use_get_generated_keys: true
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:

    swift:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        username: username
        password: password
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        dbCreate: validate #// one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:1521/serviceName
        properties:
           maxActive: -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
           testOnBorrow: true
           testWhileIdle: true
           testOnReturn: true
           validationQuery: "SELECT 1 from dual"

environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521:serviceName
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
                username: xxx
                password: zzz
                properties:
                   maxActive: -1
                   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
                   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
                   numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
                   testOnBorrow: true
                   testWhileIdle: true
                   testOnReturn: true
                   validationQuery: "SELECT 1 from dual"

            swift:
                driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
                username: report_ro
                password: Read4rpt!
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                dbCreate: validate #// one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
                url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@serverName:1521/serviceName
                properties:
                   maxActive: -1
                   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
                   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
                   numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
                   testOnBorrow: true
                   testWhileIdle: true
                   testOnReturn: true
                   validationQuery: "SELECT 1 from dual"
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

In my controller.groovy file i have declared the following.

`DataSource dataSource_swift` 
With the above i am getting the below error when i try to start the application.

Error

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_swift' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_swift': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_swift' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_swift': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at testingwebsockets.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_swift' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_swift': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_swift' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_swift': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1593) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_swift': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_swift' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_swift': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_swift': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.java:407) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:479) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:473) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:387) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Everything works fine when i use a single DataSource. Can anyone please let me know where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution to my problem. this is a link to the answer. Basically we need to define our datasource in application.groovy . [Grails 3.x multiple datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061488/grails-3-x-multiple-datasources)
But i was still unable to produce the same result with application.yml